# How to SELECT queries from multiple tables in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

How do I call the columns from the (let's say for example) login table which has the following columns

```
 username     password     type(whether admin/user)
```

my other table say the student table has the following

```
 firstname  lastname     address
```

What I want is  when a user logs in his account,
his account type will be validated whether he is an admin
or a user (which i already know how to implement), I need to know how to select the username and password from the login table along with the firstname, lastname and address from the student table and store them to the $_SESSION

I saw the syntax for the INNER JOIN but I'm so confused with that since it only SELECTS all columns that are common to each table

Below is a sample from my code

```
<?php
session_start();
require('config/db_con.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) !="" ) {
    header("location: user.php");
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login where l_user = '$user' && l_pass = '$pass'");
    $fetch1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student where s_username = '$user' && s_password = '$pass'");
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($fetch);
    $data1 = mysql_fetch_array($fetch1);



    if($data['l_type'] == "user" || $data['l_type'] == "User"){


    $_SESSION['username'] = $data['l_user'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $data['l_pass'];
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $data1['s_fname'];
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $data1['s_lname'];
    $_SESSION['course'] = $data1['s_course'];
    $_SESSION['yrsec'] = $data1['s_yrsec'];
    $_SESSION['sid'] = $data1['s_sid'];
    $_SESSION['lid'] = $data1['s_lid'];

        header('location: user.php');
    }
    else if($data['l_type'] == "admin" || $data['l_type'] == "Admin"){


    $_SESSION['username'] = $data['l_user'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $data['l_pass'];
        header('location: admin.php');
    }


}

?>
```

As you can see I have two SELECT queries, that was because I'm trying to find a way but failed.

PS: I know that this is prone to SQL injection but please mind that since I'm still I student. I'll learn it soon.

Comment: What is the common column in both the tables?

Comment: @Akshay none that is why I'm having problem with my inner join but for your information I have a login table with a columns l_user and l_type which is a bit close to be common to my student table with columns s_username and s_password.

Comment: The prime necessity to connect two tables is to have a common column between them.
Is l_user from login == s_username from student ?

Comment: @Akshay yes, they are equal except that their column names are different

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The current schema is flawed as their should be unique identifier (column) representing the entity (in this case user). To keep things simple, there should be a column "id" which will act as a primary key for the main user table where you're holding the user basic information and the other table can reference the same id as foreign key.

Have a look @ these two tutorials as these will clear your doubts

1: [Simple Secure Login using PHP / MYSQL](http://subinsb.com/php-secure-login-system)

2: [Inner Joins in PHP](http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/joins/)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it's sad enough that I don't have time to read this and learn but I appreciate your help I'd get back to this later on. I'm still a student and there's still a lot to learn. Sad enough that I didn't know this before hand anyway thanks

Comment: is the inner join the only solution?

Comment: I can understand, i was going through the same thing when i was in school too. The second link talks about all sort of joins including "inner" join

Comment: thanks for your help. I'll study this link well. Thank you for the ideas. Honestly I really don't know if teachers are good at defining their role. Thanks again.

Comment: I've downvoted because the tutorial at codingcyber.com is, unfortunately, completely the wrong way to do it. Not only is the material using a database extension that has been removed from PHP7, but it has SQL injection vulnerabilities, and recommends holding passwords in plaintext. This will get hacked in no time.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably merge login and student table and create a single users table instead, that would hold both login data and names and basic course information. No need to have multiple tables for that, when you have about 10 fields combined. In this case you would not need a join to query your data.

Comment: But I have another table which is the admin tables

Comment: both the columns username and password from the admin and student are being hold to my login as well

Comment: does that mean I should merge my admin, student, and login table too?

Comment: Yes, in this case you should merge the admin table as well. Although it is a known design pattern to split a table into multiple tables for efficiency purposes, but not when you have only a dozen or so fields.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I'll pass for this one for now since I don't ave time to pass my project since it'll be submitted today anyway thanks for the information this sure is a good experience.

Comment: You refuse to read anything related to joins, you refuse to consider merging the tables. What exactly are you looking for by posting this question?

Comment: I didn't refused to read anything about joins in fact I've got a basic grasp of it now thanks to all of your suggestion. The reason as to why I can't merge those table is because I've got to recheck most of my codes 1 by 1 which sadly enough doesn't give me enough time. Anyway thanks for the idea again.